# Get irony-mode to automatically load .config_clang

Tags: hooks, completion, company-mode

So [`irony-mode`](http://melpa.org/#/irony) scans include directories through a file called `.clang_complete`, which looks like something like: `-I./include/`

However, it does not automatically load this file. Rather, I have to go into the source file  and call `irony-cdb` and then load it manually by hitting `l`. I tried:

`(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'irony-cdb-load-compile-options)`

But it did not do anything. In fact, `irony-mode` wouldn't work period. I am trying to use `irony-mode` as a `company-mode` backend.

**Q:** How would I make this process automatic?

Comment: I edited my answer with the new usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a more recent version of irony-mode to have automatic loading. This feature is supported since irony-mode's version `0.2.0-cvs`. `M-x irony-version` to know you version.

To load the compile options manually the method has changed, you can call the interactive function `irony-cdb-autosetup-compile-options` manually: `M-x irony-cdb-autosetup-compile-options RET`.

To make this process automatic, you only need to add call this function automatically when irony-mode is enabled. This is easily done with a the [`add-hook` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Setting-Hooks.html#Setting-Hooks):

In your irony-mode configuration add:

```
(add-hook 'irony-mode-hook 'irony-cdb-autosetup-compile-options)
```

See also https://github.com/Sarcasm/irony-mode#configuration

Comment: Ok I'll try this as soon as I can!